# In Swift, how to pick media files from iCloud, Box, etc. using UIImagePickerController

Tags: swift, icloud, box

I am using UIImagePickerController to pick images/video files from the photolibrary/camera roll.  However, I also would like to give the option of picking these media files from other apps such as iCloud, Box, etc.  Preferable, a link such as "More Apps" in the same screen as the photolibrary screen.  Similar to what is seen in "Whatsapp".  I am not an expert in Swift, and any help provided is much appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `UIImagePickerController` for that, you use `UIDocumentPickerViewController`

Comment: Thank you so much.  I will try implementing using UIDocumentPickerViewController.